# Spring Security CSRF with enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I have this form in jsp file:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="advertForm" onsubmit="return checkAddress();" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text:</td>
        <td><form:input path="advert.text"/></td>
        <td><form:errors path="advert.text" cssClass="error"/></td>
    </tr>
    <table id="fileTable">
        <tr>
            <td><input name="images[0]" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="images[1]" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1"><a style="text-decoration: none" href="/"><input type="button" value="Cancel"/></a></td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
    </tr>
      <input type="hidden"
             name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
             value="${_csrf.token}" />
</table>
</form:form>
```

and this AdvertForm class:

```
public class AdvertForm {
    private Advert advert;
    private List<MultipartFile> images;

    public Advert getAdvert() {
        return advert;
    }

    public void setAdvert(Advert advert) {
        this.advert = advert;
    }

    public List<MultipartFile> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(List<MultipartFile> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
}
```

In corresponding controller I receive data using this parameter:

```
@ModelAttribute("advertForm") AdvertForm advertForm
```

The problem is when **csrf** in sping-security.xml is disabled it works fine - I can see chosen files in advertForm.getImages(), but when I enable csrf it stops working with:

```
Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080
```

I tried to resolve this problem with this steps:

1. I added multipart filter before securityFilterChain:

   ```
   <filter>
       <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```
2. I defined filterMultipartResolver:
   `<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" /></bean>`

And added it to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        ......,
        /WEB-INF/springWebMultipartContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

3. Enabled CasualMultipartParsing in Tomcat 7 (I am using standalone library to run from IDE)

   ctx.setAllowCasualMultipartParsing(true)

Now form works - I don't receive any csrf errors. But when controller receives advertForm parameter advertForm.getImages() returns null, but advertForm.getText() returns text entered by user. In logs I can see this line:

```
DEBUG  CommonsMultipartResolver - Found multipart file [images[0]] of size 3117 bytes with original filename [11111111.txt], stored in memory
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to mention that I defined this bean:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

This was a problem. After removing this bean all works fine.